# How does this work: passing in parameters into const function that takes no parameters, but used in return statement?

Tags: javascript

Title is probably not very clear but here is an example demonstrating something I came across and failed to understand fully. The only difference between method1 and method2 is where the function call is made.

```js
const method1 = (() => {
    return (name) => {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
})();
    
const method2 = () => {
    return (name) => {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
};
    
console.log(method1("Wayne")); // prints hello Wayne
console.log(method2("Wayne")()) // prints hello undefined
```

There are two things I don't understand about this.

- Firstly, how is the input parameter accessed in method1 when it takes no parameters?
- Secondly, why does this work in method1, where the function call is attached to the const declaration, and not in method2, where the function call is made in the console.log statement?

Comment: `method1` does take one parameter, `name`. The arrow function with no arguments, `(() => { ... })` is _immediately invoked_, returning the arrow function with one argument `(name) => { ... }`. In the second case you don't invoke the outer function immediately, so are passing `"Wayne"` to the wrong function -> `method2()("Wayne")`

Answer (score 0):

method2() => that returns a function with params "name" so :
put

```js
const method1 = (() => {
    return (name) => {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
})();
    
const method2 = () => {
    return (name) => {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
};
    
console.log(method1("Wayne")); // prints hello Wayne
console.log(method2()("Wayne")) // prints hello Wayne
```

Answer (score 0):

About method1, what is assigned to it is what is returned by the function below, which we can call `method1OuterFunction`:

```
() => {
    return (name) => {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
}
```

This is wrapped and called by this notation: `(method1OuterFunction)()`, that is, wrapping a function with the first pair of parentheses and invoking it with the second pair of parentheses. This is one of the ways of achieving an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression - running a function immediately upon declaration without first assigning it).

So, what would be assigned to `method1` is what is returned from invoking the said `method1OuterFunction` as above, and according to your code, that is another function, which is as below:

```
(name) => {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
```

With this, it is clear why invoking this returned function that is stored in `method1` can be invoked as follow: `method1("Wayne")` to return `hello Wayne`.

About method2, while the function assigned to it is also a higher-order (so called because it returns a function) function as below:

```
() => {
    return (name) => {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
}
```

the higher-order function isn't immediately invoked like `method1OuterFunction`, thus what is assigned directly to `method2` is the function just above. This outer function does not have a parameter and upon invocation by writing `method2()` or `method2("Wayne")`, makes no difference in that it wouldn't use the argument, and would return the same function that is below in both cases:

```
    return (name) => {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
```

It is this returned function that can now be invoked with an argument that would be substituted for its name parameter. This is what `@Alwani Anis` was pointing to when he wrote: `method2()("Wayne")`, which first invokes method2, and then calls the function that is returned by that with `"Wayne"`.

So, what you wrote before for `method2` in the second `console.log`: `method2("Wayne")()` would first return this inner function while not using the argument "Wayne" at all, and then call the returned inner function with no arguments, thereby making `name` to be `undefined` as a declared variable that a function's parameter is upon the function's invocation until it is assigned the value from the argument used to call the function, thus why you got `hello undefined`